# Forecasting using ARIMAX in R

Tags: r, time-series, modeling, forecasting

I used to forecast sales of computers at a weekly level in SAS, based on broadly two parameters - Pricing and  Marketing spends (vehicle level - hence several variables). This was easy in SAS as I could use `PROC ARIMA`.

Could you help me to transition to R? I have imported the dataset, performed the `auto.arima` and analysed p - values for some variables. However I am unaware as to how to proceed with forecasting, for the next 26 weeks. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use the "forecast" function.  The h parameter is the number of periods out.

Answer (score 5):

R has a built-in ARIMAX procedure called `arima`. To get the X part, use the `xreg=` argument. If you don't have exogenous variables and don't use `xreg=`, note that the the "Intercept" result may not indicate what you think it indicates.

So if you're using a ARIMAX(1, 2, 3)(1, 0, 0) model with dependent variable sales (monthly data), and an exogenous variable nasdaq (and you have a prediction for nasdaq of nasdaq.pred), you'd do:

```
model <- arima (sales, order=c(1, 2, 3), seasonal=list (order=c(1, 0, 0), freq=12),
                xreg=nasdaq)

pred <- predict (model, newxreg=nasdaq.predict)
```

Comment: I think you mean `TSA::arimax()`

Answer (score -2):

Suppose Your ARIMA model is Testing then ot forecast for next 26 weeks is:

```
Forecastedvalue<-forecast.Arima(Testing, h=26)
```

Hope this helps